# Find all duplicate ids and add unique key

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to find all duplicate ids when the page is relaod:

Let's say we have html like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
```

The idea is to find duplicate ids and add +1 or something like that:

What I want to achieve is:

```
<input type="radio" id="name1" />
<input type="radio" id="name2" />
<input type="radio" id="name3" />
<input type="radio" id="last1" />
<input type="radio" id="last2" />
```

JS

```
 $('[id]').each(function(){
  var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
      $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + i);
 });
```

Any ideas? Thank you all.

Comment: I think you would be better served fixing the mechanics that create the duplicate ids instead of focusing on repairing it afterwards.

Comment: your code will give different id's .apart from id's in order it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you serve valid HTML rather than manipulating Ids.

---

However, You are were close as attribute value selector may return multiple elements, You need to iterate the matching elements

```js
var handled = [];
$('[id]').each(function() {
  if (handled.includes(this.id)) {
    return;
  }
  var elemets = $('[id="' + this.id + '"]');
  if (elemets.length > 1) {
    handled.push(elemets.attr('id'));
    elemets.attr('id', function(index, v) {
      return v + (index+1);
    });
  }
});

//For Readablity
$('[id]').each(function(){
  console.log(this.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
 var allId = [];
 var data = [];
 $('[id]').each(function(){
  var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(allId.indexOf(this.id) < 0){
    data[this.id] = 1;
    allId.push(this.id);
  } else {
    data[this.id]++;
  }
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + data[this.id]);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery:

```js
const ids = {}

document.querySelectorAll('[id]').forEach(node => {
  if (ids[node.id] !== undefined) {
    ids[node.id] += 1
  } else {
    ids[node.id] = 1
  }
  node.id = `${node.id}${ids[node.id]}`

})

document.querySelectorAll('[id]').forEach(node => console.log(node))
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="name" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
<input type="radio" id="last" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];
var i =0;
 jQuery('[id]').each(function(){
    if(a.indexOf(this.id) !== -1){ //checks if id exists in array
        i++;
    }
    else{
        i = 1;
        a.push(this.id);
    }
    jQuery(this).attr('id', jQuery(this).attr('id') + i);
 });
```

Explaination : I am storing each new id in array. At each iteration it checks whether the id is repeated, if so then the attribute is incremented to 1.

Comment: Add some explanation  to remove your answer from low quality posts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var  i = 0; 
 ('[id]').each(function(){
  var allIds = $('[id^="'+this.id+'"]').length
  var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
   var i = allIds - ids.length + 1
      $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + i++);
 })
```